# Parse log4j log files within java code

Tags: parsing, log4j, otroslogviewer

Is there anyway to parse log4j files in your source code directly? I know that there are software's (chainsaw, otroslogviewer) that help you view them outside however looking for something that will help you do it within java code (and maybe return a Log object or something for every entry parsed?)

Comment: Check answer on topic Parsing Log4j Layouts from Log Files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623974/parsing-log4j-layouts-from-log-files/6624135#6624135

Answer (score 1):

log4j's LogFilePatternReceiver can do that